# A Python lib to generate logical schemes

Tags: python, data-visualization

[image]
Hello. Is there any python library for generating such schemes? I mean some simple logical schemes, when one parent node has two children nodes and every child node has its own 2 children nodes. I’m not sure that pyplot or matplotlib can do the job in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you are looking for a library that can draw networks and graphs.

Have a look at [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) and [this example](https://spyhce.com/blog/python-networkx-library).